# Perl checking if network interface is up (linux)

Tags: linux, perl, interface

everyone, I am currently working on a script in perl to check if certain interface is up.

I have tried different methods in linux I tried reading /proc/net/dev which did work but in my if statement I had it compare against eth1 and it always said eth1 was up even though it was not in /proc/net/dev the interface will only be in there is it was up (I have a usb ethernet adapter and wasn't even plugged in)

At the moment I went the cheap route.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$cheapway = `ifconfig eth1`;

if($cheapway){
   print "$cheapway";
}

else {
   print "eth1 is down";
}
```

I mean this works, but it feels like bad programming practice.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the file `/sys/class/net/<interface>/operstate` in Linux to determine an interface's state. The following should work for eth1:

```
my $interface = 'eth1';
open(my $fh, '<', "/sys/class/net/$interface/operstate") or die $!;
my $state = <$fh>;
close($fh);
chomp($state);

if ( $state eq 'up' ) {
  print "Interface $interface is up\n";
else {
  print "Interface $interface is down\n";
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, you have it to chomp and close before the if statement, I had close after mine.. and I didnt have chomp in there... I will give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: Jordanm the code seems to work.. to a degree.. if the directory is not there it gives "no such file or directory at line 4" and it stops the script from there and not continuing to the if statement.

Comment: @andyADD - Just change the `die` message to "Interface doesn't exists" if you want something more appropriate.

Comment: @andyADD - You don't *have* to close at all, but it's good practice.